# Create road speed limit segments with linear referencing

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-desktop, events, linear-referencing, dynamic-segmentation

I have a route-feature class and a point feature class with speed limit signs. In ArcMap I am capable to reference the signs on the route with help of a reference field and using the locate features along a route tool . So now I have the signs referencend on the routes and these referenced signs have a measure-field.

Now I am trying to create a line or route feature class with speed limit information on it but I can not find out how? The goal is that I have route segments that say: on route 1, from 0m to 1000m speed limit is 50kmh, from 1000m to 1337m speed limit is 80kmh and so on...
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: How are you dealing with direction of travel?

Comment: I am not. The only "direction" I use use is the values from 0m to Xm. But they have nothing to to with the actual travel direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to look at **[Make Route Event Layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003m00000008000000)** (Linear Referencing), using an Event Type of LINE.

If you need more help then the other topics to use in searches (and which I've added as tags) are **Dynamic Segmentation** (even Chainage), and **Events**.